# Module parse failed: The keyword 'private' is reserved

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I got an error in my angular 6 project as below:

> Module parse failed: The keyword 'private' is reserved (29:12) You may
>   need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. | export {
>   AuthService }; | this.changeMemberPhoto(this.currentUser.photoUrl); |
>   constructor(private, http, HttpClient); | { } |
>   changeMemberPhoto(photoUrl, string);

The related codes:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {JwtHelperService} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { User } from '../_models/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'auth/';
  jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();
  decodedToken: any;
  currentUser: User;
  photoUrl = new BehaviorSubject<string>('../../assets/user.png');
  currentPhotoUrl = this.photoUrl.asObservable();
  this.changeMemberPhoto(this.currentUser.photoUrl);

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

changeMemberPhoto(photoUrl: string) {
  this.photoUrl.next(photoUrl); 
}

login(model: any) {
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model).pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
      const user = response;
      if (user) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user.user));
        this.decodedToken =  this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(user.token);
        this.currentUser=user.user;
        this.changeMemberPhoto(this.currentUser.photoUrl);
      }
    })
  );
}

register (model: any) {
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'register', model);
}

loggedIn() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
}

}
```

I double or triple checked and didn't find any typos, does anyone know what caused this problem? thanks!

Comment: You cannot have `this.changeMemberPhoto(this.currentUser.photoUrl)` directly in the class. It should be inside a class method or inside the constructor, and preferably after `currentUser` has been defined.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is really a stupid fault. The problem is fixed after deleting this line. It has been used in login method.